# How does /dev/fd relate to /proc/self/fd/?

Tags: symlink, directory-structure, devices

```
$ ls -l /dev/stdin /dev/fd/0
lrwx------ 1 tim tim 64 2011-08-07 09:53 /dev/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 2011-08-06 08:14 /dev/stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
$ ls -l /dev/pts/2 /proc/self/fd/0
crw--w---- 1 tim tty  136, 2 2011-08-07 09:54 /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 tim tim     64 2011-08-07 09:54 /proc/self/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/2
```

1. What differences and relations are between /dev/fd/ and
   /proc/self/fd/? Do the two `fd`'s mean `both floppy disk`, both `file  descriptor`, or one for each?
2. What are /proc/self and /proc usually for?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`/dev/fd` and `/proc/self/fd` are exactly the same; `/dev/fd` is a symbolic link to `/proc/self/fd`. `/proc/self/fd` is part of a larger scheme that exposes the file descriptor of all processes (`/proc/$pid/fd/$number`). `/dev/fd` exists on other unices and is provided under Linux for compatibility. `/proc/*/fd` is specific to Linux.

Answer (score 5):

They mean *file descriptor* in each case. Look at my answer to [the second part of your question about `/dev/` files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18239/understanding-dev-and-its-subdirs-and-files/18245#18245). And also [what file descriptors are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).

The `/proc` filesystem is described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/contents-of-proc). `/proc/self` contains the properties of the current process.